# Converting random letters within a string to Upper/Lower Case

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a bot for my discord that I am adding a command to post one of those spongebob memes that you may have seen on twitter recently. I basically have to convert a string that the user enters, for example `This is the string they would enter` and it would convert it to something like this `THis iS ThE sTRinG thEy WOulD EnTEr`

I need to basically randomly set each character in that string to and uppercase or a lowercase. 
Here is what I have so for, it prints out the original string and not the converted one.

```
commands.CreateCommand("spongememe").Parameter("message", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async (e) =>
        {
            string message = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++)
            {
                message += e.Args[i].ToString() + " ";
            }

            char[] array = message.ToCharArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 1)
                    Char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                else
                {
                    Char.ToLower(array[i]);
                }
            }

            string newMessage = String.Join("", array);

            await e.Channel.SendMessage(newMessage);

        });
```

Any help on how to randomly select which characters are set to upper and lower case would be appreciated.

Comment: Char.ToLower RETURNS the new value. You have to collect those. Use a stringbuilder or a preallocated char array

Comment: `array[i] = Char.ToUpper(array[i]);`

Comment: Please decide: Do you want set **each** character or **some random** characters?

Comment: Ahh i see, works perfect now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to randomly uppercase letters from a sentence:

```
var someString = "This is the string they would enter";
var randomizer = new Random();
var final =
    someString.Select(x => randomizer.Next() % 2 == 0 ? 
    (char.IsUpper(x) ? x.ToString().ToLower().First() : x.ToString().ToUpper().First()) : x);
var randomUpperLower = new string(final.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(randomUpperLower);
```

[<== Try Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rVAsIA)

Comment: This doesn't really work if they user types in something in all caps.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the heads up. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Char.ToUpper(char c);` and `Char.ToLower(char c);` takes the char argument, transforms it either to uppercase or lowercase, and returns the transformed result. It doesn't change the char itself (see "Value and Reference Types" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).

You need to modify it to something like this:  `array[i] = Char.ToUpper(array[i]);`